# Best practise for update view after backstack from new activity

Tags: android, refresh, android-lifecycle, back-stack

I actually had an activity's fragment which contain a custom tablelayout with checkbox and goned image. Also, when the user click on a button for send mail at selected rows, I would like to update the visibility of the goned images. I called a new activity which is my mail client, so when I press back, the fragment is still there but onCreateView isn't call properly, and my view isn't refresh. So I would like to know which is the best solution to update it (without recreate my fragment programmaticaly).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want to refresh View completly without recreating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting another `Activity` for your mail client, instead of just [`startActivity(intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) use the [`startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method and override [`onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data)`.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

Define a constant for your `requestCode` and use that for `startActivityForResult` when you start the mail client. When the user returns from the mail client, `onActivityResult` will be called and the value of its `requestCode` parameter will be your constant. This is the callback you need to use to set the appropriate visibility for your `View`s.

Comment: I thought activityresult ak a setResult in the next Activity created. I will tried that, thanks. It works fine in fact :)

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to call `setResult` in the next `Activity` - it will return `RESULT_CANCELED`. If you don't distinguish between OK and CANCELED, you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You can update in `onResume()` method of fragment.For your reference purpose read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle , http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle

Comment: I was convinced I tried it before, but my method which create the tablelayout was taked in treeObserver listener, which explain the view wasn't update.

Comment: Mean, didn't understood?

Comment: I already tried refresh in resume override, but my loadContact function was taked in a listener which isn't effective when I backstack. Sorry if my english is crappy ^^'